# Given an odd length list of values in Python, how can I swap all values other than the final value in the list?

Tags: python, list

In regards to Python 2.7.12 (*disclaimer: I understand Python2 is being phased out to Python3, but the course I'm taking started us here, perhaps to understand older code bases*):

I have a list of integers whom I'd like to swap each with their neighboring value. So far, this works great for lists that are even in the number of integers they contain, however when the list length is odd, it's not so easy to simply swap each value, as the number of integers is uneven.

Giving the following code example, how can I swap all values other than the *final* value in the list?

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def swapListPairs(arr):
    for idx, val in enumerate(arr):
        if len(arr) % 2 == 0:
            arr[idx], arr[val] =  arr[val], arr[idx]  # traditional swap using evaluation order
        else:
            arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]  # this line is not the solution but where I know I need some conditions to swap all list values other than len(arr)-1, but am not sure how to do this?
    return arr

print swapListPairs(arr)
```

**Bonus Points to the ultimate Pythonic Master**: How can this code be modified to also swap strings? Right now, I can only use this function using integers and am very curious how I can make this work for both `int` and `str` objects?

Thank you so greatly for any insight or suggestions to point me in the right direction! Everyone's help at times here has been invaluable and I thank you for reading and for your help!

Comment: For strings, check the output of `"foo" < "bar"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a shorter, probably faster way based on slice assignment:

```
def swap_adjacent_elements(l):
    end = len(l) - len(l) % 2
    l[:end:2], l[1:end:2] = l[1:end:2], l[:end:2]
```

The slice assignment selects the elements of `l` at all even indices (`l[:end:2]`) or all odd indices (`l[1:end:2]`) up to and excluding index `end`, then uses the same kind of swapping technique you're already using to swap the slices.

`end = len(l) - len(l) % 2` selects the index at which to stop. We set `end` to the closest even number less than or equal to `len(l)` by subtracting `len(l) % 2`, the remainder when `len(l)` is divided by 2.

Alternatively, we could have done `end = len(l) & ~1`, using bitwise operations. That would construct an integer to use as a mask (`~1`), with a 0 in the 1 bit and 1s everywhere else, then apply the mask (with `&`) to set the 1 bit of `len(l)` to 0 to produce `end`.

Comment: A little detail on the least significant non-zero bit trick will improve this answer.

Comment: The `end` in `l[1:end:2]` is unnecessary.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: True, but I find it clearer to explicitly limit the section of the list we're working with.

Comment: @user2357112 Then you won't like the answer I just posted :-)

Comment: @user2357112 -- thank you for such an in depth response here. This is definitely some tight looking code and I'm just getting my feet wet here trying to understand the usage of `:` and `::` within the conditional statements. (//edit) To better understand this, just to recap, what you've done here is created a variable called 'end', by which we essentially round to the closest even value of our list length, correct? (If 5 for example, 4 would be the value of end)..we then use this 'end' variable to assess for even and odd indices, by which we swap them, and to note our stopping point?

Comment: @timothy-knab: Pretty much.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks again and I'll touch base with my instructors and try and study the usage of `:` and `::` more so I fully understand conceptually what's happening. I really appreciate your in-depth knowledge and willingness to help and hope someday I'm a python master like yourself and all others here! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is easier to do *without* `enumerate`.  Note that it never, ever makes decisions based on the *contents* of `arr`; that is what makes it work on anything, not just a pre-sorted list of integers starting from 1.

```
for i in range(len(arr)//2):
    a = 2*i
    b = a+1
    if b < len(arr):
        arr[a], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[a]
```

Exercise for you: is the `if` actually necessary? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4):

You could iterate through the length of the list with a step of two and try to swap values (and except index errors).

```
def swap_list_pairs(arr):
    for index in range(0, len(arr), 2):
        try:
            arr[index], arr[index+1] = arr[index+1], arr[index]
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return arr
```

This will work for all data types.

As [Copperfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5644961/copperfield) suggested, you could get rid of the try-except-clause:

```
def swap_list_pairs(arr):
    for index in range(1, len(arr), 2):
        arr[index-1], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[index-1]
    return arr
```

Comment: you could also start the range in 1 and do instead `index-1` that way you never face IndexError

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman - this is a really nice example here as well, thanks to @Copperfield also for tightening it up - the other code examples here are great but the `:` and `::` operators (are these operators?) is still throwing my brain for a bit of a loop -- the answer you've provided definitely makes sense, and essentially, because it moves in a step of two, any items with an odd index would be simply ignored, correct? Thank you greatly for responding and for your insight!

Comment: @timothy-knab here the list is processed 2 element at the time, and if the list have a odd number of element, then it can't take 2 elements in the last step so the last element is untouched. So is not that odd indexes are ignored, is that only the last element is ignored if the list have a odd size

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @user2357112 but I prefer it this way:

```
arr[1::2], arr[:-1:2] = arr[:-1:2], arr[1::2]
```

Demo:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> arr[1::2], arr[:-1:2] = arr[:-1:2], arr[1::2]
>>> arr
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]

>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> arr[1::2], arr[:-1:2] = arr[:-1:2], arr[1::2]
>>> arr
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Comment: thank you also for your contribution here building off of @user2357112 -- I am still having trouble fully understanding the concept of the `:` and `::` and exactly how to understand them...would you be willing to give me an example using some pseudocode as to exactly how these evaluate the array? I really appreciate the cleanliness of this code and thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

looks like `:` and `::` confuse you a little, let me explain it:

Sequences type of object in python such as list, tuple, str, among other provide what is know as a slice, it come in 2 flavors:

Slicing: a[i:j] selects all items with index k such that i <= k < j. When used as an expression, a slice is a sequence of the same type. This implies that the index set is renumbered so that it starts at 0.

Extended slicing with a third “step” parameter: a[i:j:k] selects all items of a with index x where x = i + n*k, n >= 0 and i <= x < j.

In both cases i, j and/or k can be omitted and in that case suitable values are used instead

Some examples

```
>>> arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
>>> arr[:]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
>>> arr[:3]
[10, 20, 30]
>>> arr[1:3]
[20, 30]
>>> arr[1::2]
[20, 40, 60]
>>> arr[::2]
[10, 30, 50, 70]
>>>
```

the working of this can also be illustrated with the following function

```
def the_slice(lista, ini=None, end=None, step=None):
    result=[]
    if ini is None:
        ini = 0
    if end is None:
        end = len(lista)
    if step is None:
        step = 1
    for index in range(ini,end,step):
        result.append( lista[index] )
    return result



>>> the_slice(arr,step=2) # arr[::2]
[10, 30, 50, 70]
>>> the_slice(arr,ini=1,step=2) # arr[1::2]
[20, 40, 60]
>>>
```